# How can I show that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1+\log i}{n} = \Theta(\log n)$

Tags: summation, logarithms

How can I show that $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1+\log i}{n} = \Theta(\log n)$$

What I've tried: $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1+\log i}{n} = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n {\log i} = \frac{\log(n!)}{n^2} = \frac{\log n^n}{n^2} = \frac{n\log n}{n^2} = \frac{\log n}{n}$$

Comment: why is $$\log(n!)=\log(n^n)$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner , something I learned in the course. $logn! = \Theta(nlogn)$

Comment: It should be $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1 + \log i}{n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \log i$$

Comment: @NP-hard now it makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: but $$\log(n!)=\log(1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot...\cdot n)=\log(1)+\log(2)+...+\log(n)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That is true sir. but how does it contradict what you've asked

Comment: we get $$\log(a \cdot b)=\log(a)+\log(b)$$ for $$a,b>0$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $log(n!) = \Theta(nlogn) = log(n^n)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \log i \leq n \log n
$$

Comment: I just used that. see my edit. Still got $n$ in the denominator.